# Whats Error in my javascript code

Tags: javascript

My html code is working in jsfiddle..
Below is the link : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c13n5a7e/)

But when tried to exceute in desktop im getting following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at six.php:8
>   (anonymous) @ six.php:8

Html :

```
<html>
<title>capacity utilization factor</title>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    CUF PERFORMANCE
    <div id="wrapper">
      <select id="select" name="options">
            <option>Select The Value</option>
            <option id="hourly" value="a">Hourly</option>
            <option id="daily" value="b">Daily</option>
            <option id="monthly" value="c">Monthly</option>
            <option id="yearly" value="d">Yearly</option> 
             </select> /div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

JS :

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var wrappElement = document.getElementById('wrapper');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (select.value == 'a') {
    var dateElement = document.createElement('input');
    dateElement.type = 'dateTime';
    wrappElement.appendChild(dateElement);
    var dateElement = document.createElement('input');
    dateElement.type = 'dateTime';
    wrappElement.appendChild(dateElement);
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: where and how is the script code loaded into the web page?

Comment: JSFiddle is default executing onload. You need to wrap your code in `window.onload=function() { ... }`

Comment: or move code to the bottom of body

Comment: 1. What browsers support datetime? 2. show and hide a div with the fields instead of changing the DOM each time

Comment: @JaromandaX...thanks man